# jquery chosen limit character and disable dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-chosen

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=7515b9e

How to disable dropdown list of chosen plugin.
I want to make a mimimum 3 character limit on search ... If result match then show dropdown list not like on first click all result showing as you can see on image link.

Comment: Please provide a code sample that you are trying to target.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4or7bstp/

Answer (score 1):

Chosen doesn't have the options to set min search length.
If you're not locked into chosen try select2 it has all the options your looking for. ie. Min search length

Comment: thanks for the information about min search length.
how can i disable the on click dropdown result list.. i want to show them only while searching 
code :- https://jsfiddle.net/4or7bstp/